# IEnumerable<> returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, ienumerable

I'm returning a null in my code: **(the var cat line)**

```
public class CategoryItemsViewModel
{
    public ICategoriesRepository categoriesRepository;

    public IEnumerable<Categories> GetCategories()
    {
        var cat = categoriesRepository.Categories;

        return cat;

    }
}
```

here is the interface:

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface ICategoriesRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Categories> Categories { get; }
        void SaveCategory(Categories category);
        void DeleteCategory(Categories category);
    }
}
```

here is the class:

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is empty... Did you try some basic debugging already? You know: Visual Studio is shipped with an excellent debugger!

Comment: Are you able to perform other CRUD operations, such as add a new category?

Comment: Well, there are myriad of things than can be wrong. What exactly is `Categories` property doing? This is the part that is probably central to your issue.

Comment: How is the `categoriesRepository` member initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have so far is fine - it's just incomplete.

You don't need a setter as someone else suggested either - in fact in this case it's probably better not to have one.

You do need a concrete implementation of your interface ICategoriesRepository eg:

```
public class CategoriesRepository : ICategoriesRepository
{
    private readonly ModelContainer db= new ModelContainer();

    public IQueryable<Categories> Categories 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.db.Categories;
        }
    }

    public void SaveCategory(Categories category)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    public void DeleteCategory(Categories category)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Then you will need to add a line to your viewmodel:

```
public class CategoryItemsViewModel
{
    public ICategoriesRepository categoriesRepository;

    public IEnumerable<Categories> GetCategories()
    {
        // This is to instantiate your repository.  It may be a better idea to do this
        // when it is declared, above.
        categoriesRepository = new CategoriesRepository();

        var cat = categoriesRepository.Categories;

        return cat;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set anything that's not `null` to the `Categories` property in the `ICategoriesRepository` object, and you can't, with the given interface.  You have a property with an automatic getter an no setter.  This means it will only ever be able to return `null`.  If there is a setter (either public or privite) then you would be *able* to set it to something else.  (You would also need to have a line of code that actually did it.)  You could also use a custom getter that actually returned something other than just the backing field.  (This is common for derived data.)

Comment: No setter does not mean it will always return null, and in this case a setter is probably not wanted.  Just return the categories directly from the model container (see my answer).

Comment: @PeteOakey I said you need either a setter or a non-auto getter.  You choose to provide an implementation of the latter.  By using a custom getter you are able to return some other thing that can be modified.  A property with an automatic getter and nothing else will only ever return that type's default value.

Comment: so you did - hmm, can't undo my down-vote until an edit is made to the question though.  I tried editing myself but didn't work.

Comment: @Pete: Since you have less than 2000 reputation, it has to be reviewed by other users. It <del>is</del> <ins>was</ins> in the queue to be reviewed, but was rejected for the reason 'too minor'.

Comment: @PeteOakey I made an edit to the post without changing it's meaning.